# Have an issue installing Visual Studio 2010 RC on Windows XP SP3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation

I had an issue installing **Visual Studio 2010 RC** on **Windows XP SP3**?

(Have installed same ISO package on Vista and worked fine...)

Setup would fail no matter what I tried:

> **Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate RC Setup**
>
> A problem has been encountered while
>   loading the setup components.
>   Canceling setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by "Mikael Söderström" on MSDN Forums:

> Display the language bar at the
>   taskbar, right-click on it and choose
>   settings. Then you **remove the hand
>   writing support** from the list.

See 
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/setupprerelease/thread/dbcdcd52-d162-4460-9920-33c9ab54b36f

Answer (score 0):

I was installing VS2010 on a windows 7 machine inside a "Windows XP Mode" instance and it was failing.

The reason being the install files were not on the Windows XP instance.

Copying the setup files to within the XP instance fixed the issue.